# Inconsistent inequalities

Tags: inequality

I want to prove that the following two inequalities cannot hold simultaneously

$\beta_0^2(\beta_1-1)\geq \beta_1$

and

$\beta_1^2(\beta_0-1)\leq \beta_0$, 
where $1<\beta_0<\beta_1<2$

Comment: How did you approach the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is a statement rather than a question...

Suppose that they do hold 'simultaneously' and I will use $a:=\beta_0$ and $b:=\beta_1$.

Add them together to get

$$\begin{align}
b+ab^2-b^2& \leq a^2b-a^2+a
\\\Rightarrow a^2b-ab^2-a^2+b^2-b+a&\geq0
\\ \Rightarrow ab(a-b)-(a-b)(a+b)+1(a-b)&\geq 0
\\ \Rightarrow (a-b)(ab-a-b+1)&\geq 0
\\ \Rightarrow (a-b)(a-1)(b-1)\geq 0
\end{align}$$
which is a contradiction because $a<b\Rightarrow a-b<0$ and $a,b>1\Rightarrow (a-1),(b-1)>0$.

Comment: maybe I made a mistake, the right statement is that :two inequalities cannot hold simultaneously 

$\beta_0^2(\beta_1-1)\leq \beta_1$

and  


$\beta_1^2(\beta_0-1)\geq \beta_0$, 
where $1<\beta_0<\beta_1<2$

Comment: Sorry I am assuming that they do hold simultaneously... the contradiction means that they do not as required.

Comment: yes, I understand,that statement cannot be true. try the new one.

Comment: "Try the new one"?

Comment: Try to prove the new statement in the comment

Comment: No. Why don't you? You have done nothing here.